# how to compute in game loop until the last possible moment

Tags: opengl, optimization, 3d, game-engine, vsync

As part of optimizing my 3D game/simulation engine, I'm trying to make the engine self-optimizing.

Essentially, my plan is this.  First, get the engine to measure the number of CPU cycles per frame.  Then measure how many CPU cycles the various subsystems consume (min, average, max).

Given this information, at just a few specific points in the frame loop, the engine could estimate how many "extra CPU cycles" it has available to perform "optional processing" that is efficient to perform now (the relevant data is in the cache now), but could otherwise be delayed until some subsequent frame if the current frame is in danger of running short of CPU cycles.

The idea is to keep as far ahead of the game as possible on grunt work, so every possible CPU cycle is available to process "demanding frames" (like "many collisions during a single frame") can be processed without failing to call glXSwapBuffers() in time to exchange back/front buffers before the latest possible moment for vsync).

---

The analysis above presumes swapping back/front buffers is fundamental requirement to assure a constant frame rate.  I've seen claims this is not the only approach, but I don't understand the logic.

I captured 64-bit CPU clock cycle times just before and after glXSwapBuffers(), and found frames vary by about 2,000,000 clock cycles!  This appears to be due to the fact glXSwapBuffers() *doesn't* block until vsync (when it can exchange buffers), but instead returns immediately.

Then I added glFinish() immediately before glXSwapBuffers(), which reduced the variation to about 100,000 CPU clock cycles... but then glFinish() blocked for anywhere from 100,000 to 900,000 CPU clock cycles (presumably depending on how much work the nvidia driver had to complete before it could swap buffers).  With that kind of variation in how long glXSwapBuffers() may take to complete processing and swap buffers, I wonder whether any "smart approach" has any hope.

---

The bottom line is, I'm not sure how to achieve my goal, which seems rather straightforward, and does not seem to ask too much of the underlying subsystems (the OpenGL driver for instance).  However, I'm still seeing about 1,600,000 cycles variation in "frame time", even with glFinish() immediately before glXSwapBuffers().  I can average the measured "CPU clock cycles per frame" rates and assume the average yields the actual frame rate, but with that much variation my computations might actually cause my engine to skip frames by falsely assuming it can depend on these values.

I will appreciate any insight into the specifics of the various GLX/OpenGL functions involved, or in general approaches that might work better in practice than what I am attempting.

PS:  The CPU clock rate of my CPU does not vary when cores are slowed-down or sped-up.  Therefore, that's not the source of my problem.

Comment: Unless you are doing something very simple you require to pre-process (run time processing will probably use more CPU than it saves, unless you have some simple case with many data) a object graph of your code so you know data and instruction layout and with a data dependency graph you can group better processing groups. Says you have C that needs A and B, you could decide to compute all As then all Bs and finally all Cs or maybe process few KB of As and Bs and then the Cs depending on them. (because you have also a cache for instructions! and you have also a BUS)

Answer (score 1):

This is my advice: at the end of the rendering just call the swap buffer function and let it block if needed. Actually, you should have a thread that perform all your OpenGL API calls, and only that. If there is another computation to perform (e.g. physics, game logic), use other threads and the operating system will let these threads running while the rendering thread is waiting for vsync.

Furthermore, if some people disable vsync, they would like to see how many frames per seconds they can achieve. But with your approach, it seems that disabling vsync would just let the fps around 60 anyway.

Comment: But in that approach, don't my other threads need to know when they can call various GLX/OpenGL functions without blocking?  Seems like my code ends up not being very efficient either way.

Comment: Don't use GL calls in multiple threads (you won't get increased performance and that will probably be buggy depending on the driver implementation). Only one rendering thread must perform all the GL calls. However, the other threads can do some culling, animation, etc. on your 3D world objects and feed the rendering thread with the data needed for each draw call (e.g. vertex buffers, shaders, uniform values, etc.)

Comment: SwapBuffers doesn't block. After calling SwapBuffers only the next OpenGL call that forces the CPU to wait for operations on the back buffer that alter its contents (so drawing, but not finishing) will block until completion.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to re-interpret your problem (so that if I missed something you could tell me and I can update the answer):

Given *T* is the time you have at your disposal before a Vsync event happens, you want to make your frame using  *1xT* seconds (or something near to 1).

However, even if you are so able to code tasks so that they can exploit cache locality to achieve fully deterministic time behaviour (you know in advance how much time each tasks require and how much time you have at your disposal) and so you can theorically achieve times like:

*0.96xT*

*0.84xT*

*0.99xT*

---

**You have to deal with some facts:**

1. You don't know T (you tried to mesure it and it seems to hic-cup: those are drivers dependent!)
2. Timings have errors
3. Different CPU architectures: you measure CPU cycles for a function but on another CPU that function requires less or more cycles due to better/worse prefeteching or pipelining.
4. Even when running on the same CPU, another task may pollute the prefeteching algorithm so the same function does not necessarily results in same CPU cycles (depends on functions called before and prefetech algorihtm!)
5. Operative system could interfere at **any time** by pausing your application to run some background process, that would increase the time of your "filling" tasks effectively making you miss the Vsync event (even if your "predicted" time is reasonable like *0.85xT*)

At some times you can still get a time of

*1.3xT*

while at the same time you didn't used all the possible CPU power (When you miss a Vsync event you basically wasted your frame time so it becomes wasted CPU power)

---

**You can still workaround ;)**

**Buffering frames:** you store Rendering calls up to 2/3 frames (no more! You already adding some latency, and certain GPU drivers will do a similiar thing to improve parallelism and reduce power consumption!), after that you use the game loop to idle or to do late works.

With that approach it is reasonable to exceed *1xT*. because you have some "buffer frames".

Let's see a simple example

- You scheduled tasks for *0.95xT* but since the program is running on a machine with a different CPU than the one you used to develop the program due to different architecture your frame takes *1.3xT*.
- No problem you know there are some frames behind so you can still be happy, but now you have to launch a *1xT* - *0.3xT* task, better using also some security margin so you launch tasks for *0.6xT* instead of *0.7xT*.
- Ops something really went wrong, the frame took again *1.3xT* now you exausted your reserve of frames, you just do a simple update and submit GL calls, your program predict *0.4xT*
- surprise your program took *0.3xT* for the following frames even if you scheduled work for more than *2xT*, you have again 3 frames queued in the rendering thread.
- Since you have some frames and also have late works you schedule a update for *1,5xT*

By introducing a little latency you can exploit full CPU power, of course if you measure that most times your queue have more than 2 frames buffered you can just cut down the pool to 2 instead of 3 so that you save some latency.

---

Of course this assumes you do all work in a sync way (apart deferring GL cals). You can still use some extra threads where necessary (file loading or other heavy tasks) to improve performance (if required).

Comment: Yes, I can see how one can take advantage of triple or quadruple buffering to get better average performance and avoid "once-in-awhile" misses of vsync.  I rejected that approach when I started this project because it increases the lag between human input and visual response to that input.  However, as the importance of making simulations and games work over the internet, I might have to reconsider this issue, though I'm not sure what my ultimate decision will be.  The point being, even with super-high-speed internet bandwidth, the latency just can't be reliably reduced very far... yet.

Comment: More and more it seems like the authors of GPU drivers try to hide everything and make everything *appear* asynchronous to applications.  For example, glXSwapBuffers() not blocking (though apparently at least glFinish() does still block).  From small clues, I'm beginning to think I may have no choice but to trust the GPU driver writers to an extent, and just focus on finishing each frame in whatever is the measured average frame time (take the elapsed time from the 64-bit CPU clock timer for 256 frames, then divide by 256).  Then thereafter make decisions based upon that CPU clock timer.

Comment: I'm not concerned with "different CPUs" and those kinds of issues.  Those issues will be automatically dealt with by automatically disabling features until the average frame rate slightly exceeds 30FPS.  Once the set of "supportable features" is found in this manner, from then on the issue is knowing when a certain frame has more or less demand than average (like more or less collisions to deal with on a given frame), and then knowing that, either do more or less "optional" work that can be put off until later frames if necessary without harming the quality of the resulting simulation or game.

Comment: Oh, and yes, the engine will constantly consume every CPU cycle on every CPU core/thread until none remain.  I'm also not worried about being preempted by other applications, because the kind of applications the engine is intended for are inherently intended to be the only application running (besides the most fundamental services that any OS must perform).  What do I mean by optional work that can be done this frame or sometime later?  Compute and update the list of objects near and massive enough to generate sufficient gravitational force on any one object to be worth computing every frame.

Comment: even if you are running 1 application, the operative system will interrupt your application ANYWAY. for example in my computer (win Vista) sometimes the process get paused for something like 13-15 ms regardless it is the only running application. If you want to avoid "once-in-awhile" (happens hundreds times in a  minute) missed v-syncs events, you have no choice apart buffering. By the way you'll be happy to know the latency is not perceived, because drivers are already doing that, you are just helping them to be more power efficient (using for a flight sim)

Comment: whil for works, it depends on your codebase, if you have a plain ECS (entity component system) design you just need to update certain systems at lower frequencies (very used in many commercial games). If you have a task based design you can just have a prioritized task queue(scheduler) where task priority is setted up-front and priority also increase overtime (late tasks). If you have no problem turning off certain features to target 30 fps you for sure have no problem implementing a interleaved update or a priority queue. ECS and tasks make debuggin certain interactions harder by the way

Comment: by buffering you are just filling the GPU command queue "enough" before stopping doing that for a while. Drivers will do what they want with that queue. Theorically there is a latency in doing that, in practice I never noticed it.